# Starting point to find a job and place to live in Sweden while being abroad?

Tags: immigration, accommodation, job-hunting, sweden

A good friend of mine, who lives in Switzerland, wants to leave her country and move to Sweden. The reasons for this are neither being job related, nor rooted in having a community or friends there that she wants to live with. Instead, her wish to live in that country stems from a deep love for the country, its culture and predominantly for the local scene.

This situation leaves her with having neither a guarantee of a job, nor a place to live when she will arrive, both being a necessity when starting to live in a country. To help her, I have some related questions about the topic, that I hope to find answers to here:

1. Are there any guidelines to finding a job abroad in Sweden? Looking for work is rather difficult when you're not around, so I thought maybe there are general steps one should follow.
2. Are there communities that help you migrating to Sweden? I can't imagine that she's the first person who wants to live there, without communities, employer or partners being the reason for the migration.
3. In general - Is searching a job and moving to the location of employment the best option one has? Or is moving to a place with a good infrastructure a better option?

To give additional information that might be of help answering the question: my friend already lived in Sweden for 2 years, and speaks the language to a B2 level. She has a Bachelor's degree in Agronomy, but hasn't worked in the field for 4 years now. She is a Swiss citizen, and doesn't have a Swedish identity number.